# MySQL: how to make an order on select by giving specific score to special records

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a simple table, for example:

```
id | name   | category
------------------------
1  | banana | 1
2  | orange | 1
3  | fruit  | 1
4  | potato | 2
5  | car    | 0
```

I have a lot of special filters that should assign a special score for the list to show.
Here is the mechanism for this example:

1. IF "name" is "banana" or "orange", score = score + 2
2. IF "name" is "fruit", score = score + 1
3. IF "name" is "potato", score = score + 0
4. IF "category" > 0, score = score + 1

So in my results I need to have

```
id | name   | category | score
-------------------------------
1  | banana | 1        | 3 ( condition 1+4)
2  | orange | 1        | 3 ( condition 1+4)
3  | fruit  | 1        | 2 ( condition 2+4)
4  | potato | 2        | 1 ( condition 3+4)
5  | car    | 0        | 0 ( no match)
```

And finally I want to order the results by score.
I can't create new column, because the conditions are selected by user.
What will be MySQL query?

Answer (score 3):

One possible approach:

```
SELECT id, name, category,
       IF(category > 0, 1, 0) + 
       (CASE name WHEN 'banana' THEN 2
                 WHEN 'orange' THEN 2
                 WHEN 'fruit' THEN 1
                 ELSE 0 END)
        AS score
FROM ttt
ORDER BY score DESC
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee1b2/20)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  name, 
  category, 
  nameCondition + catCondition AS Score
FROM
(
    SELECT
      id, name, category,
      CASE 
        WHEN name IN ('banana', 'orange') THEN 2
        WHEN name = 'fruit'               THEN 1
        WHEN name = 'potato'              THEN 0
        ELSE 0
       END AS nameCondition,
       CASE 
         WHEN  category > 0 THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END AS catCondition
    FROM tablename
) AS t;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5c6d/2).

This will give you:

```
| ID |   NAME | CATEGORY | SCORE |
----------------------------------
|  1 | banana |        1 |     3 |
|  2 | orange |        1 |     3 |
|  3 |  fruit |        1 |     2 |
|  4 | potato |        2 |     1 |
|  5 |    car |        0 |     0 |
```